# Limpar campo ao selecionar lista

Tags: html, advpl

Sou novo ainda nessa área de programação e estou me batendo para ajustes em um formulário.

Tenho uma seleção para fazer em um campo, onde se o usuário escolher correio, o campo email "que já está preenchido" deve ficar em branco.

Código:

```
<fieldset id="dados_cadastro">
    <legend>Dados da Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o de Forma de Envio de Boleto</legend>
    <div class="cadastro_line">
        <label style="width: 175px">Envio de Boleto:</label>
        <select name="boKa" id="">
            <option value=" "></option>
            <option value="1">Correio</option>
            <option value="" selected="selected"> Email</option>
            <option value="3"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cadastro_line">
        <label style="width: 175px">E-mail:</label>
        <input name="aaa" class="text" type="text" style="width: 175px" value="">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Isso está sendo programado em advpl / HTML.

Comment: William, consegue colocar o código,talvez um print para compreendermos melhor.

Comment: Em JS, tu pode apagar o conteudo do campo com esse comando
: document.getElementById('campo').value=''; // Limpa o campo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara aqui tem um exemplo simples com JS, se o valor que vc selecionar no `<option>` do `<select>` for o `value` do "correio" vc limpa o valor de `Email`

```js
let sel = document.querySelector('[name="boKa"]');

sel.addEventListener('change', limpa);

function limpa() {
    if (sel.value == 1) {
        let valor = document.querySelector('[name="aaa"]');
        valor.value = '';

        console.log('limpou o email');
    }
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="dados_cadastro">
    <legend>Dados da Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o de Forma de Envio de Boleto</legend>
    <div class="cadastro_line">
        <label style="width: 175px">Envio de Boleto:</label>
        <select name="boKa" id="">
            <option value=" "></option>
            <option value="1">Correio</option>
            <option value="" , selected="selected" , ''>Email</option>
            <option value="3"></option>

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cadastro_line">
        <label style="width: 175px">E-mail:</label>
        <input name="aaa" class="text" type="text" style="width: 175px" value="algo preenchido">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```